# Drone Editor: Rotate a Build

Tags: drone-the-game

I built a drone backwards in Drone the Game.  It would be a pain to try to rebuild it!  How can you rotate it, instead of having to rebuild it?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that this option is going to be available later on, seeing this game is still in developement.  It just has to wait for the moment.